# Factoring a quadratic mod $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, factoring

I have $p=1 \mod 3$.
I am trying to show that $x^2-x+1=(x-a)^2 \mod p$ for some $a$.
So far I have that $x^2-x+1=x^2-2ax+a^2 \mod p$.  Which mean that $2a=1 \mod p$ and $a^2=1 \mod p$

The first identity tells us that $a=\frac{p+1}{2}$ Using this in the second identity we have $(\frac{p+1}{2})^2=1\mod p$. So we get $\frac{p^2+2p+1}{4}=1\mod p$. But now we run into trouble because this implies $1=4\mod p$ or in particular $p=3$. Have I done something wrong here, or am I mistaken that its possible to have $p=1\mod 3$.

for added context, $x^2-x+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

Comment: Don’t use `\mod`. The spacing is all wrong. For the binary mod operator, use `\bmod`. Compare $p=1 \mod 3$ (what you use) and $p=1\bmod 3$ (using `\bmod`). To produce $p=1\pmod{3}$, use `\pmod{3}`.

Comment: There is something wrong with the question: consider $p=7$. For $x=0$, we have $a^2 \equiv 1 \implies a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 7$. Then putting $x=1$ in either case produces a contradiction: $(a-1)^2 \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: Do you really want the polynomial to split as a single factor squared? Or do you just want $x^2 - x + 1 = (x-a)(x-b)$ for some $a$ and $b$? Anyway, note that $x^2 - x + 1$ is the sixth cyclotomic polynomial, so any root of $x^2 - x + 1$ must also be a root of $x^6 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2 + x + 1)(x^2 - x + 1)$. What do you know about the order of $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$?

Comment: your righty, I dont know why I was so fixed on having it split as a square. I needed to produce an element of order p in the ring, but for that it was sufficient to have it split as a product of linear factors.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you so much for this comment. I will only use \pmod in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an element $a$ of order $3$ then $$x^2 -x+1=(x+a)(x+a^{-1})\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$$

$x^{p-1}-1$ (of degree $p-1$) has $p-1$ distinct roots in $\Bbb{F}_p$ thus $$x^{p-1}-1=\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}(x-n)\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$$
Take any root $b$ of $x^{p-1}-1$ which is not a root of $x^{(p-1)/3}-1$, the order of $b$ divides $p-1$ but not $(p-1)/3$ thus it is $3m$ so that $a=b^m$ works.